# Having problems with partitioning my sd card on android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, partition

I'v been trying to partition my sd card to use it as internal storage at my android, but things don't work out.

I followed the description here: https://www.nextpit.com/how-to-format-microsd-cards-as-internal-storage

When I partition my disk into private, my phone alerts me that my sd card has been unexpectedly dismounted, and after a while the phone restarts by itself. My storage still haven't become larger, and my phone tells me my sd card is corrupted and should be formatted.

I'm using a galaxy A6 with android 10, and both my sd card and phone is 32 GB in storage size.

Comment: `been trying to partition my sd card ` Why? Leave all to your Android device. Why would you intervere?

Comment: Further its unclear where you did try to do so. With an Android device? Using your PC? Or other?